# NSFetchedResultsController with predicate based on dependent property

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a Core Data iPhone app that displays `Subscription` entities where any of its `items` are not `read`. In other words, I construct a predicate like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY items.read == NO"]
```

While this works for the initial fetch, it doesn't affect `Subscription` entities when I modify an `Item`, so the `NSFetchedResultsController` never reevaluates the `Subscription` entities. What would be a better way of structuring this so that the `Subscription` entity will be updated whenever an item's `read` property is set?

I did try creating a property `unreadCount` on `Subscription` and using `keyPathsForValuesAffectingUnreadCount` to return a set containing `items.read`. I didn't expect this to work, and it didn't. I get an exception from `_NSFaultingMutableSet` telling me that the `read` key is not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two solutions:

1. When you modify an item have the fetched results controller perform the fetch again and reload the table view.
2. Add a property to Subscription (such as your unreadCount or a boolean hasUnreadItems) and keep it properly updated. Use this property in your fetched results controller.

You can get the set of unread items for a Subscription named "aSubscription" like this:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"read == NO"];
NSSet *unreadItems = [aSubscription.items filteredSetUsingPredicate:pred];
```

Comment: I was hoping someone would swoop in and offer some brilliant method I hadn't thought of, but I suspect you're right, particularly with solution #2. I think I'll just make `unreadCount` a "real" property and update it whenever an item gets updated.

Comment: Just an update for you, I ended up adding properties to `Subscription` so that `NSFetchedResultsController` would only need to observe one entity. Curiously, though, unless I fault in the updated objects in `managedObjectContextObjectsDidChange:`, `NSFetchedResultsController` still doesn't see them. It's a bit of a kludge, and I'm concerned about performance implications of faulting in a bunch of objects individually, but it does work now.

Comment: Weird. How are you updating the new property?

Comment: Are you adding the property to just a subclass or actually putting the property into the Core Data entity in the model?  Sounds like you are just putting it in the subclass which, as you have seen, does not work very well.  gerry3's suggestion was to add a property to the entity in the model itself and keep that updated.

Answer (score 4):

You've encountered a bug with `NSFetchedResultsController` where notifications are not received (or evaluated?) for the property changes of the related entity.

In this case, the `read` property of `items` is not being "watched" for changes.

Rather than re-structuring, you can workaround the problem by faking the change of the `item`s in the relationship. i.e. When you change `item.read`, also pretend to change `item`.

My experience only goes as far as a one-to-one relationship. I'm not clear on how you would handle your one-to-many relationship, when you're only changing a single key of one of the many. This may work:

```
thisItem.read = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
[thisItem.subscription willChangeValueForKey:@"items"];
[thisItem.subscription didChangeValueForKey:@"items"];
```

That should send a notification that a relationship (`subscription.items`) is changing on the `subscriptions` objects being watched by the `NSFetchedResultsController`.

I can provide a working example of a one-to-one relationship case that works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I should have read the question closer.

I've worked around a very similar situation by setting the NSFetchedResultsController cache and then refreshing my UITableView in the `viewDidAppear:` method. I had a pretty small dataset and there was no noticeable performance penalty for frequently refreshing the data.

Comment: Yes, you will be notified if `Subscription` changes. But modifying an `Item` doesn't modify the `Subscription`, so the fetched results controller doesn't see any changes to notify the delegate about.

Comment: The only downside to totally reloading the table view is that you lose some state, e.g. the selection status. I'm sure that the reloading will be infrequent enough not to impose a performance penalty, but I don't want to give up that little bit of UI feedback.